Is it reasonable to extract the Schottky barrier height from the zero-bias transmission spectrum?
The following question is based on discussions What's meaning of zero energy reference point in the energy-axis of zero-bias transmission spectrum extracted by sisl.get_sile('systemlabel.TBT.nc')? and Where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra?.
The zero bias transmission spectrum corresponds to zero bias DOS of the device region without any electrodes, and the zero energy reference point in the transmission spectrum is consistent with the fermi energy of the device region.
If the device region is a pure semiconductor, then the Fermi level in the device region is randomly placed between the conduction band and the valence band. However, since there is always a portion of the metallic electrode extending into the device region, serving as a screening layer, a heterojunction of metal and semiconductor actually appears in the device region. The Fermi level at this time will be the Fermi level of the heterojunction, and the distance from the Fermi level to the conduction band minimum should be the Schottky barrier height.
Is it reasonable to extract the Schottky barrier height from the zero-bias transmission spectrum using the above way?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
